# How to populate a field from an array of objects of another a collection that it's not a model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

for example I have two collections,
1st collection schema (test):

```
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "le nom d'examen est obligatoire!"],
    },
    year: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "l'année est obligatoire"],
    },
    questions: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Question",
      },
    ],
    clinicalCase: [
      {
        _id: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          index: true,
          required: true,
          auto: true,
        },
        text: String,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

2nd schema:

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  test: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Test",
  },
  questionString: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "la question est obligatoire"],
  },
  explanation: String,
  options: [option],
  tag: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Tag",
  },
  clinicalCase: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  }
});
```

so my problem here is when I query 2nd schema, I want to populate the clinicalCase field with 1st schema, is it possible to do it with populate method or not ? can you help me with it please

Comment: Can you post the full definitions of both schemas?

Comment: @Ipizzinidev I just updated the post, you can check it again, thank you!